# $.ajax won't work if dataType mentioned

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on WordPress to retrieve subcategory when user select main category from drop down list.
All work is done using ajax. But problem is if I mention dataType to json nothing return and if don't than it work as expected and I know that I am receiving valid Json.

Here is jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var select = $('#main_cat');
            select.on('change', function(){
                var temp = $('#main_cat option:selected').text();
                console.log(temp);
                var data = {
                    action: 'my_action',
                    security: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce; ?>',
                    cat: temp
                };
                $.ajax({

                    url: ajaxurl,
                    data: data,
                    type: 'post',

                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);    

                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

And this is response I am receiving. It appear to be array but when I use typeOf(response) it shows string. I also tried instanceofArray and same thing.

Here the exact response code: If I use json_encode this is what i receive but jquery still consider it string.

```
[" <option>Auto mobile<\/option>"," <option>Shopping<\/option>"]
```

and this is what i am receiving with json_encode

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  <option>Auto mobile</option>
    [1] =>  <option>Shopping</option>
)
```

Here is PHP code .

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {

    check_ajax_referer( 'my-special-string', 'security' );


    $args = array(

        'child_of'                 => get_cat_ID($_POST['cat']),
        'orderby'                  => 'name',
        'order'                    => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'               => 1,
        'hierarchical'             => 1,

    );


    $temp = array();
    foreach (get_categories($args) as $cat) {
        $temp[] =  " <option>$cat->cat_name</option>";

    }
    print_r($temp);


}
```

Comment: It looks like you're returning an array which jQuery will detect as `script` by jQuery. If you manually specify `json` datatype, the parser will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

That response isn't `JSON`. Looks like PHP `print_r`, use

```
echo json_serialize($output);
```

`$output` being the variable you were using `print_r` on.

Comment: It is not recognising json_serialize as recognised function and i am receiving an error

Comment: I recall having an issue with it not data typing JSON properly, add JSON headers. `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;');`

Comment: I actually added contentType: in ajax call and same problem occur no response.

Comment: Well `$.parseJSON('[" <option>Auto mobile<\/option>"," <option>Shopping<\/option>"]')` is working correctly... Could always accept it as a string then parse it manually.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how I totally inexperience to Jquery or perhaps point to article or documentation for parsin string in jquery.

Comment: `var parsedString = $.parseJSON(string);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using `print_r()` in backend PHP code:

When you are using `datatype` in `ajax` Try this in backend:

```
echo json_encode($output_array);
```

Comment: i also tried it and i am receing json but jquery still consider it string

Comment: @Epistemologist have you used `datatype:json`

Comment: this exactly what i used.  dataType: 'json', but when i use it i only receive 0 that is an error

Comment: Well that output  I pasted in my post is actually from console.

Comment: @Epistemologist you have pasted backend output of json_encode. Its fine. I want output of `console.log` jquery. Is it an object? It should be. as i have used in demo